# Why doesn't !important override inline style in IOS browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, browser

Anyone know why this is happening and how to override the inline style in IOS browsers?

`overflow-y: hidden !important` overrides the inline style in OSX/Chrome:

[image]

`overflow-y: hidden !important` does not override the inline style in IOS9.0/Safari (and IOS9.0/Chrome):

[image]

Comment: Why the javascript tag?

Comment: Maybe the solution involves javascript?

Comment: Would you like me to remove the tag?

Comment: You might use javascript to set the rule (or not), but it's a CSS question to know what rule to set.